# Are truffles (the edible fungi) allowed in carry on?

Tags: food-and-drink, ryanair

My friends are coming to visit me and will bring me some food. They are flying with Ryanair from Italy to Portugal and they only have hand luggage (cabin bags).
Can they bring truffles (type of fungus with a very strong-smell) on board?

Answer (score 1):

The [general terms & conditions of carriage](https://www.ryanair.com/ie/en/useful-info/help-centre/terms-and-conditions/termsandconditionsar_696869348) of Ryanair state the following about prohibited items: 
"Items which are reasonably considered by us to be unsuitable for carriage because they are dangerous, unsafe or by reason of their weight, size, shape or character, or which are fragile or perishable having regard to, among other things, the type of aircraft being used."

Strictly taken, if you don't package them well, I would say that truffles are unsuitable for carriage because of their character (the smell). If you do package them well (vacuum) and one would not be able to smell them, there shouldn't be a problem according their terms & conditions.